# How to read Map of lists from Yaml file using Java

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

I have such Yaml file:

```
accept: 
- "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
accept-encoding: 
- "gzip, deflate"
accept-language: 
- "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
- "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,lt;q=0.6"
connection: 
- close
- keep-alive
dnt: 
- 1
referer: 
- "https://www.google.com/"
- "https://www.yahoo.com"
- "https://www.bing.com/"
upgrade-insecure-requests: 
- 1
- 0
x-real-ip: ~
```

And I try to read this with :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
Map user = mapper.readValue(new File("/home/a/headers.yaml"), Map.class);
System.out.println(ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(user, ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE));
```

but only can get single level of nesting. this I believe should be map of lists...

Comment: Please provide your expected output. The user Map is {accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate], accept-language=[en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8, ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,lt;q=0.6], connection=[close, keep-alive], dnt=[1], referer=[https://www.google.com/, https://www.yahoo.com, https://www.bing.com/], upgrade-insecure-requests=[1, 0], x-real-ip=null} which seems ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your code it outputs:

```
java.util.LinkedHashMap@6500df86[
  accessOrder=false
  threshold=12
  loadFactor=0.75 
]
```

Which is the string representation of the Map object, not of what is inside.

**The hard way:**

If you want to use `ReflectionToStringBuilder`, I am afraid you will have to implement your own style by extending `ToStringStyle`. And your style would have to go through the Map and extract the keys and values.

**The simple way:**

However, you can achieve pretty much what you want with simple loops, and it is lot simpler, here is an example:

```
Map<String, List <Object>> user = 
    mapper.readValue(new File("/home/a/headers.yaml"), Map.class);

for(Map.Entry<String, List<Object>> entry : user.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    List<Object> values = entry.getValue();
    if(values != null) {
        for (Object value : values) {
            System.out.println("  - " + String.valueOf(value));
        }
    }
}
```

Given your file, it outputs:

```
accept
  - text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding
  - gzip, deflate
accept-language
  - en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
  - ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,lt;q=0.6
connection
  - close
  - keep-alive
dnt
  - 1
referer
  - https://www.google.com/
  - https://www.yahoo.com
  - https://www.bing.com/
upgrade-insecure-requests
  - 1
  - 0
x-real-ip
```